# Applying Group Leaders Optimization to Quantum Belief Systems

Tags: quantum-gate, circuit-construction, optimization

**Context:** I am particularly interested in [quantum cognition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quantum_cognition) & would like to use a tool like [pyZX](https://github.com/Quantomatic/pyzx) to perform the following types of optimizations.

---

In [Preparing a (quantum) belief system](https://arxiv.org/abs/1708.08250) they "establish a theoretical result showing that in the absence of constraints on measurements, *any state can be obtained as the result of a suitable sequence of measurements*."

It is also stated in the paper that "achieving the desired belief state *may require a sequence of measurements that is not practically feasible*."

---

**How could the [Group Leaders Optimization Algorithm](https://arxiv.org/abs/1004.2242) be applied in the above context to generate *practically feasible sequences of measurements*?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The GLOA is just an optimization algorithm (another genetic algorithm actually). So as long as your problem translates into an objective function you seek to minimize/maximize, this would be possible (even by another genetic algorithm).

I suggest to first think how you encode your problem for the optimization. For example, a sequence of discrete and/or real variables. The objective function is also important to specify. I am guessing here you would look at the fidelity with the desired belief state.

The only thing however you would have to consider is the definition of being practically feasible as I don't know what the authors refer to

> a sequence of measurements that is not practically feasible.

However, let us take the example of the GLOA applied to find the decomposition of a unitary operator U into a sequence of gates (or circuit) within a predefined set, which you can find the explanation in this [article](https://aip.scitation.org/doi/abs/10.1063/1.3575402). This was discussed in this [question](https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/4426/understanding-the-group-leaders-optimization-algorithm/4429#4429) before. Maybe it will help you relate to your problem.
The idea is to represent a circuit as a sequence of variables taking integer or real values. For instance, let's try to find the decomposition of the Toffoli gate using the set of gates $\{V,Z,S,V^{\dagger},R_x(\theta) \}$ and we allow to use maximum 5 gates. We start by randomly creating candidate circuits. Here is one example of candidate circuit (showing you an encoding of the problem) :

> **1** 3 2 0.0; **2** 3 1 0.0; **3** 2 1 0.0; **4** 3 2 0.0; **5** 1 3 0.75

You see you have 5 sequences of 4 numbers (3 integers and one real). Each sequence represent an application of a gate.
`1 3 2 0.0`, in this case, means apply the $V$ gate (index 1 in the set) on qubit $3$ controlled by qubit $2$ with an angle $0.0$ (note that with the $V$ gate there is no angle but say you were playing with like rotation gates, this becomes relevant). So it is like a problem of 20 variables to tweak for the optimization scheme.

The optimization will consist of finding the solution circuit represented by a unitary operator $ U_a $ close to the unitary operator of interest $ U_t $; using GLOA which maximize the trace fidelity (here serving as an objective function telling us how close the candidate is to the solution):
$$ \mathcal{F} = \frac{1}{N}|\operatorname{Tr}(U_aU_t^{\dagger})| $$

Say you were looking for quantum states, the objective function would be for instance to minimize a distance between two quantum states with one being the desired solution. In the [book of Nielsen and Chuang](https://docs.google.com/viewer?url=http%3A%2F%2Fmichaelnielsen.org%2Fqcqi%2FQINFO-book-nielsen-and-chuang-toc-and-chapter1-nov00.pdf), you have chapter 9.2 which is about quantifying how two quantum states are close.

Comment: Could you potentially elaborate on encoding methods, objective functions, fidelity & feasibility?

Comment: I can take the example of the GLOA used to find a decomposition of a unitary operator if you want and you can relate to quantum belief state yourself. 

For the feasibility, it is just that I don't know what authors refer to as a sequence of measurements that is not practically feasible. And I am not ready to go into the details of the subject now as my efforts are directed on another topics. 
Would that be enough?

Comment: Any additional information you would be willing to provide would be greatly appreciated!