# Does the GLOA have any advantage over the Solovay-Kitaev algorithm?

Tags: quantum-algorithms, complexity-theory, solovay-kitaev-algorithm

The [Solvay Kitaev algorithm](https://arxiv.org/abs/quant-ph/0505030) was discovered long before the [Group Leaders Optimization algorithm](https://arxiv.org/abs/1004.2242) and it has some nice theoretical properties. As far as I understand, both have exactly the same goals: given a finite dimensional unitary operator, they decompose the operator into basic quantum gates. I couldn't find any theoretical results about the time complexity or convergence time or error bounds for the GLOA as such. Does the latter (GLOA) have any practical advantage over the former at all, in terms of convergence time or anything?

P.S: For a detailed description of the GLOA, see: [Understanding the Group Leaders Optimization Algorithm](https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/4426/understanding-the-group-leaders-optimization-algorithm)

Comment: I don’t know anything about GLOA, but nowadays there are better algorithms than Solovay-Kitaev

Comment: As a side question, do you have any link to resources about these algorithms? Or at least their name? @DaftWullie

Comment: @Nelimee Sure, I just had to be on a decent computer to find the link I had. Try this one: https://arxiv.org/abs/1212.6253

Comment: Thanks! But even if the algorithm is better in terms of complexity, it does not replace the SK algorithm. I though you were speaking of an algorithm as general as SK.

Comment: @Nelimee the Ross-Selinger algorithm is not just better in terms of complexity than the Solvay-Kitaev algorithm, it has been implemented in practice and is very fast (were talking seconds to achieve errors in the $10^{-3}$ range and is the standard tool for doing approximate circuit synthesis on Clifford+T gate sets. In what way does it not replace the SK algorithm?

Comment: @Connor Ross-Sellinger and SK algorithms have different domains of application. SK is more general (work for any matrix, any gate basis) but less efficient whereas Ross-Sellinger only works for Z-rotations with the Clifford+T gate set, but is more efficient.

Comment: Right ok sure... I think to be precise you could say that S-K works in Lie groups (like the special unitary group), whereas R-S works whenever the entries of the matrices in your gate set lie in a certain convenient number field (which happens for Clifford + T and a few other of the universal gates sets). I guess you are also right in the sense that R-S only works for qubit gates, where as S-K methods could perhaps work for qudits.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like GLOA algorithms are a type of *genetic algorithm*. Genetic algorithms are *heuristic algorithms* which often do not have any specified time complexity nor accuracy (which is likely why you couldn't find anything). So why do we even use these algorithms you might ask? The answer is that often they work and if they do so in a reasonable amount of time, then why not use them. Often they are easy to program and can be applied to problems where one might have no idea how to find an optimal solution.

On the other hand the SK algorithm is an *exact or deterministic algorithm* with polynomial complexity in $O(\log(1/\epsilon))$ where $\epsilon$ is the desired accuracy of the quantum gate. The SK algorithm (unlike heuristic algorithms) takes advantage of the fact that quantum gates are elements of the unitary group $U(d)$, which is a Lie group and therefore a smooth manifold in which one can make conclusions about the geometry and distance between points.

GLOA's may have advantages when *engineering* quantum circuits as it may be possible to incorporate other desired aspects of circuit design into the optimization. However, they will not be as efficient nor optimal as the SK algorithm (or the more powerful number theoretic approximation algorithms for $U(d)$).