# Genetic algorithm does not converge to exact solution

Tags: quantum-algorithms, optimization

I'm trying to evolve quantum circuits using genetic algorithms as they did in this paper [Decomposition of unitary matrices for finding quantum circuits: Application to molecular Hamiltonians](https://aip.scitation.org/doi/abs/10.1063/1.3575402) (Daskin & Kais).

So given a unitary target matrix ($U_t$), the task is to evolve a circuit that approximates $U_t$ (let's call it $U_a$). This is the function I'm maximizing:

$$F = \frac{1}{2^n}|\operatorname{Tr}(U_aU_t^{\dagger})|$$ (where *n* is the number of qubits)

My circuit encoding is a little bit different, I'm using a json string representation, here's an example of a random circuit:

```
[{0: ('Y', -1, None), 1: ('Td', -1, None), 2: ('Y', -1, None)}, 
{0: ('Z', 2, None), 1: ('Y', -1, None)}, 
{0: ('Vd', 1, None), 2: ('V', -1, None)}, 
{1: ('X', -1, None), 2: ('Y', 0, None)}, 
{0: ('Td', -1, None), 2: ('V', 1, None)}, 
{1: ('S', -1, None), 2: ('X', 0, None)}]
```

Every dictionary item in the array is a column in the format `{target: (gate, control, param)}`. The value -1 means no control, and None means there are no parameters. Here's a visual representation of this circuit:

```
+--------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+
| qubit  | col_0 | col_1 | col_2 | col_3 | col_4 | col_5 |
+--------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+
| q0-->  |   Y   |  Z•2  |  Vd•1 |   I   |   Td  |   I   |
| q1-->  |   Td  |   Y   |   I   |   X   |   I   |   S   |
| q2-->  |   Y   |   I   |   V   |  Y•0  |  V•1  |  X•0  |
+--------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+
```

So far, I've been successful at finding very small circuits (with 2 "columns"). The problem comes when trying to evolve solutions for more complex circuits. For example, the paper shows this solution for the Toffoli unitary:

[image]

My algorithm is not able to find this solution or any other exact solution to this problem. I tried changing the selection method, crossover and mutation rates, but the fitness value never exceeds 0.85. After some generations, it seems that all individuals are converging to the same non-optimal circuit (this happens even with uniform crossover and random selection).

For crossover, I've tried one-point crossover and uniform crossover. The mutation operation can do these things:

1. If it's a controlled gate, it can change the type of the target gate, can change the position of the control, can swap target/control, can remove the control, or can shuffle a column.
2. If it's not a controlled gate, it can change the type of gate or introduce a control.

I don't see what else can I do to improve these operators. In the paper, they also have a continuous *angle phase* parameter, but this particular circuit solution does not use it anyway.

Another curious fact: for this particular problem, the *empty circuit* has a fitness of 0.75. If a take the exact solution (from the image) and change a single gate, I can get a fitness of 0.5. So, an empty circuit has better fitness than a circuit which is a small step from the exact solution. This is very confusing, I don't see where the GA will find "optimal sub-circuits" to exchange during crossover.

It should be noted that the paper uses a more sophisticated version of a GA, but for the reasons stated above, I don't think it will make a difference in my case.
So what I'm missing or how can I improve this? Thank you!

### Edit

It seems the GLOA did it's work. The algorithm found this for the Toffoli unitary:

```
+--------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+
| qubit  | col_0 | col_1 | col_2 | col_3 | col_4 |
+--------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+
| q0-->  |   I   |   I   |   I   |   I   |   I   |
| q1-->  |  Z•2  |   I   |   I   |   I   |  S•0  |
| q2-->  |   I   |  Vd•0 |  Z•1  |  V•0  |   I   |
+--------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+
```

But I limited the kind of gates it could use, now I'll try with all the gates.

Comment: **Related:** [Understanding the Group Leaders Optimization Algorithm](https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/q/4426) & [Does the GLOA have any advantage over the Solovay-Kitaev algorithm?](https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/q/4469).

Comment: @Blue I'm implementing GLOA, let's see what happens.

Comment: Well, it worked. The GLOA found this for the Toffoli unitary: *[{1:('Z', 2, None)}, {2:('Vd', 0, None)}, {2:('Z', 1, None)}, {2:('V', 0, None)}, {1:('S', 0, None)}]*

Comment: Great! Oh, so you weren't using the GLOA before? Did you use some other genetic algorithm?

Comment: I was using a vanilla GA, with elitism. I've tried all kinds of stuff, but everyone was converging to a suboptimal solution.

Comment: I think that the GLOA works like a ensemble of GAs, just like a ML ensemble of models. When there are few knobs to turn, all individuals in a classic GA tend to become equal, the GLOA try to avoid this I think.

Comment: That's right. The strategy used by GLOA may explore more the search space compared to just use one set of  candidates. Each leader may take a different path while sharing a bit of information with others.

Comment: Is your code available in the public domain?