# Evolving a quantum circuit using a genetic algorithm

Tags: programming, circuit-construction, optimization

I've written a small quantum circuit simulator in python, so now I'm trying to evolve some circuits via genetic algorithms. My encoding is very simple, it's just a rectangular table of strings representing the gates. Here's a example of a random circuit:

```
+--------+--------+--------+-------+--------+-------+
| qubit  | col_0  | col_1  | col_2 | col_3  | col_4 |
+--------+--------+--------+-------+--------+-------+
| q0-->  |   I    | CNOT_2 |   S   |   Z    |   H   |
| q1-->  | CNOT_0 |   T    |   S   |   I    |   T   |
| q2-->  |   S    |   I    |   S   | CNOT_1 |   S   |
+--------+--------+--------+-------+--------+-------+
```

My first attempt is to generate the Toffoli gate, which input/output I encoded as follows:

```
inputs = [[0, 0, 0], [0, 1, 0], [1, 0, 0], [1, 1, 0]]
output_zero_probs = [[1, 1, 1], [1, 0, 1], [0, 1, 1], [0, 0, 0]]
```

So there are 4 input tests, and for each one there is the correspondent output. The variable *output_zero_probs* is the probability of measuring 0 for each wire for each input. Note that the last qubit holds the answer.

So for example, if the input is [1, 1, 0], the output should be [1, 1, 1], which correspondes to output_zero_probs of [0, 0, 0].

The fitness functions is just some measure of similarity between the circuit output and the expected output probabilities. The circuit dimension was fixed to 3 x 17, ie, 3 qubits x 17 columns. The mutation operator just changes a random cell, and the crossover operator exchanges an entire 'column' between 2 circuits.

So far it was not able to find the correct solution, it seems to evolve a bit, then it get stuck. Is this a feasible problem for a GA? If so, how can I improve on this? I mean, how can I 'push' the circuit to the right direction?

Thanks for your attention!

---

**EDIT:**

Now I think it's better to compare the final state of the system with the expected final state, instead of using probabilities, because these may change depending on the measures (I'm not sure if this reasoning is correct).

Follow up question: [Genetic algorithm does not converge to exact solution](https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/5833/genetic-algorithm-does-not-converge-to-exact-solution)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So in your example, you try to find the quantum circuit representing the Toffoli operation.
I would then change my objective/fitness function and compare the unitary matrix representing the operation. You can use an minimization objective like : 
$$ \mathcal{F} = 1-\frac{1}{2^n} |\operatorname{Tr}(U_aU_t^{\dagger})| $$

with $ U_a $ is the unitary of the generated solution and $ U_t $ the unitary you are trying to get. The trace part of this objective means try to get $ U_aU_t^{\dagger} $ to the identity matrix on $n$ qubits.

Also, when using a genetic algorithm, many strategies can be tried, and may generate better solutions than others. You can look at this [question](https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/4426/understanding-the-group-leaders-optimization-algorithm) where a genetic algorithm is used for circuit decomposition.

Comment: Thanks. Is there any difference between using the unitary x final state superposition as a target? Or they are equivalent? (see my edit note)

Comment: @Fernando They would be equivalent but the unitary takes into account all possible states one would apply the operation. So it is better to specify the unitary than trying all computational basis states.

Comment: I'm trying this and reading some papers, it's not converging to the exact solution for the Toffoli target. I'm wondering what I'm missing, because these papers seem to converge very fast.

Comment: Are you using the same evolution strategy?

Comment: No, that's my next plan. I'm using a vanilla GA with elitism. I also tried various selection schemas and combinations of crossover/mutations, without success so far. It gets to 0.85 very fast, but then it stops improving. This is very weird, in the Daskin paper the conversion to the Toffoli unitary is very fast.

Comment: I would try using their strategy which is different as it is like many populations evolving, so one may capture a more efficient generation. I can also think of the linear algebra you are using for getting the unitary is wrong somewhere. Are you defining it youself?

Comment: I inserted the correct solution into the population, the fitness goes immediately to 1.0, so the algebra is ok I think. It also can find small circuits. Maybe I  should open a new question with more details of what are my operators and so on.

Comment: @Fernando With this fitness, you should get a fitness of 0 if you are minimizing the one in the response.

Comment: I'm maximizing. I will open a separate question, maybe you and others could spot what I'm missing, if I give more details. Thank you so far!

Comment: Here it is: https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/5833/genetic-algorithm-does-not-converge-to-exact-solution

Comment: What if all the diagonal is 1, but the other elements are not zero? Is the trace a sufficient condition?

Comment: @Fernando Well if you are really concerned with off-elements, you can add a penalty term on them, trying to drive them towards 0.